# How to access DataTemplate in resource dictionary in library project

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I have own library project and having defined DataTemplate in ResourceDictionary (**Style.XAML**).
This (Style.XAML) resource is merged in **Generic.XAML** of WPF library.
 Created a class CustomDataTemplateSelector which is derived from **DataTemplateSelector** in my library project.
I have tried **FindResources** method. but not working.
Please share your ideas to access the DataTemplate in CustomDataTemplateSelector class.

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
 {
     FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
     if (item == null)
         return null;
     if (element != null && item != null)
     {
         if (item.ViewType != "Month")
         {
             //var dt = element.Resources["DayAppointmentControlTemplate"];
             return element.TryFindResource("DayAppointmentControlTemplate") as DataTemplate;
         }
         else
         {
             return element.TryFindResource("MonthAppointmentControlTemplate") as DataTemplate;
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: When your app is running, it runs in the context of the entry point. The exe. It's what is merged in app.xaml which ends up in resources. As in application.current.resources. The only way your element will have that resource is if you merge it in as a resource on the frameworkelement. Which would be very inefficient if there are a lot of these as you get a resource per frameworkelement instance.

Comment: It's more usual to merge resource dictionaries in app.xaml and use datatype on datatemplates rather than datatemplate selectors at all. I have rarely seen datatemplate selectors used in wpf apps for that reason. In any case, it seems odd you are looking up something from generic.xaml since the idea is that this would be switched out as part of theming. Theming is the main reason you'd use a custom control rather than user control.